# How to add a rule in one column based off the data of another

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to figure out how to create what seems like a complicated conditional formatting formula. There are 2 columns of data necessary, but one depends entirely on the other. In my case, if BT2 = Yes, then BV can't be blank. If BT2 = No, then there is no highlight needed.

So far we have come up with

=IF($BT$2 = "Yes",$BV$2 <> ISBLANK, "")

It is allowing me to use that formula, but it returns nothing.

I have posted a picture of what the rule SHOULD do if operating correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative is you to use blank for $BV2.

```
=IF($BT2="Yes",$BV2="")
```

Or to use the `"ISBLANK"` function:

```
=IF($BT6="Yes",ISBLANK(BV6))
```

A little tip, "Conditional formatting" only wants TRUE/FALSE statement, so your formula in conditional fomatting should always return either TRUE or FALSE.

[image]

Comment: I'm not ignoring this! I will try it out on Tuesday at my work computer. Thank you for the response!

Comment: Ah, i was able to make it work with that! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=AND($BT2="Yes",LEN($BV2)=0)
```

Highlight the entire `BT column` and set up the conditional formatting as above and it should work across board. If you need to add new data to BT column, simply use the **Format Painter** to copy and paste the conditional format to the new rows.

In my example below I used Column A and B instead of BT and BV but it is the same logic.

[image: example]